# Is there a way to create a new flutter project with some folder or file generated

Tags: flutter, dart, code-generation, mobile-application

So I've been creating a lot of flutter apps for freelance projects. However, I have some setup where I created a lot of folders and dart files such as constant, utils and so on. After that, I start writing the same code for a certain file such as the error page and loading widget. So how can I generate all of this since it takes 1 hour for me to finish setup the architecture and actually start the project?

Comment: create a template/boilerplate project with files and folders, duplicate it for your new project when needed or push to git repo and then clone it. What's the issue here I can't find?

Comment: @OMiShah for your information, thats what i did. the first solution i can think of.. i have the code saved. However, it still need a lot to do. i don't use github repo though because i need to create new repo for that project. in my opinion this is not an efficient way when u made a lot of project. U need to experience making a lot of project in the first place to know that's not an efficient way. That's the issue here. now i know the solution which is to use the mason package. that's what i need. Thanks though for your opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Mason](https://pub.dev/packages/mason) which can create "bricks" of templated dart code and other files.  You can create a personal favorite "create a project" brick, or even just add items to an existing project.

Comment: thanks been looking for this.. i thought the only way just to create the dart command line